# Create offline local WiFi?

Tags: wifi

I'm making a bicycle "dashcam" with the RPi. For the rear cam, I'm trying to set up something similar to how my car's dashcam works for video preview and file transfer. On that dashcam, it creates a WiFi network(not connected to the internet) and I can connect to it on my phone. I'd like to do something similar but everything I found on Google involved connecting to the internet.

Any other ideas on how to transfer the video wireless would be very welcome.

Comment: `everything I found on Google involved connecting to the internet` ... please provide links to some of the examples

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#setting-up-a-routed-wireless-access-point without the bridge does what you want.

Comment: step 1-5 from https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/ will do (first hit when searching google for "raspberry pi wifi access point without internet")